# Exporting text/plain from Google Drive

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I'm trying to export a Google Doc as text. I've tried two approaches, neither's working.

Exporting the contents, I get the contents as a byte object which I haven't been able to convert to a simple string:

```
req = service.files().export_media(fileId=file_id,mimeType='text/plain')
fh = io.BytesIO()
download = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, req)
done = False
while done is False:
    status, done = download.next_chunk()
return fh.getvalue()
```

I then get variants of codec errors

> return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
>   UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ufeff' in position 0: character maps to < undefined >

or these:

> TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

So that's a type conversion problem, I guess, and if I can solve that it'd work.

BUT, I'd much rather just use the exportLinks property to download the file as text/plain. Problem is, that's simply missing:

```
file = service.files().get(fileId=id).execute()
pprint.pprint(file)
```

> {'id': 'xxxxxxxxxx',
>
> 'kind': 'drive#file',
>
> 'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.document',
>
> 'name': 'export'}

file['exportLinks'], unsurprisingly, gives a KeyError:

> KeyError: 'exportLinks'

I've relaxed the scope so it's now 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive', so that shouldn't be the problem.

What am I missing?

Comment: exportLinks is not available in Drive API v3 - see the [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration) - "The exportLinks field has been removed from files"...

Comment: Your code sample looks just like that off the Drive API samples page, so should be correct, could you post a fuller trace of where the errors are occuring?

Comment: Ha, I was indeed using the v2 API docs, so that explains the exportLinks issue :( I've been experimenting with files.export(), but that also gives me a byte object so I'm back to the type conversion problem - will post a trace of that when I'm back in front of that PC.

You're correct re the API samples - I started with the quickstart.py sample and just plugged in the sample code. Haven't worked with the Drive API before so really feeling my way here!

Comment: Argh, char limit, and minimarkdown hates me. Basically...
Given the byte object from MediaIoBaseDownload:

print(fh.getvalue()).decode())

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fix.py", line 117, in <module>
    main()
  File "fix.py", line 113, in main
    print(contents.decode())
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
 UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ufeff' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>

decode('ascii', 'ignore') works, but ew :(

Answer (score -1):

The [Drive platform](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/integrate-open#open_and_convert_google_docs_in_your_app) allows developers to open, import, and export native Google Docs types such as Google Spreadsheets, Presentations, Documents, and Drawings. For instance, if your application is configured to open PDF files, then because Google Documents are exportable to PDF, users will be able to use your application to open those documents.

The app can download the converted file content with the [files.export](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/export) method.

```
file_id = '1ZdR3L3qP4Bkq8noWLJHSr_iBau0DNT4Kli4SxNc2YEo'
request = drive_service.files().export_media(fileId=file_id,
                                             mimeType='application/pdf')
fh = io.BytesIO()
downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
done = False
while done is False:
    status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
    print "Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100)
```

Comment: Well yes. That's the exact code sample I used, and is in the question I posted.

The problem is that it returns a byte object, which I'm not able to convert to a string. decode('ascii','ignore') works, but more destructively than I'd like.